# multiple aggregate functions with multiple tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function, aggregate

I am trying to get data for entered person, I want to pull out data as No of invoices and No of line items for particular person.

The output is

```
Entered_by  No of line items
CD               9
CD               136084
deepa             7
deepa             18
dolly             757
dolly             22350
kroshni         666
kroshni         16161
lokesh           4
lokesh           999
MHeera           639
MHeera             20427
nandini            7
nandini            5318
```

Here the data in No of line items is mixing of both ’ No of line items’ count and  ‘No of invoices’ count, I want to show like

```
Entered_by  No of line items    No of invoices
CD               136084              9
deepa               18                7
dolly               22350               757
```

Please help me with this somebody ….. 

Here is the T-SQL query

```
select ENTERED_BY, count(entered_by) 'NO OF LINE ITEMS'
from im_invoice, im_invoice_line_item, im_invoice_inventory 
where invoice_rid = invoice_fk
and invoice_inventory_rid = invoice_inv_fk
and enter_date between dateadd(mm, -3, getdate()) and dateadd(mm,0,getdate())
group by entered_by

union 

select entered_by, count(invoice_num) 'NO OF INVOICES' from im_invoice
where enter_date between dateadd(mm, -3, getdate()) and dateadd(mm,0,getdate())
group by entered_by
```

Comment: Can you clarify the relationships between the three tables? Which tables do the columns `invoice_rid`, `invoice_fk`, `invoice_inventory_rid` and `invoice_inv_fk` belong to?

Answer (score 1):

As Joe said, if you give us a more detailed description we can give you better answers, but until then, quick and dirty way to accomplish this is as follows:

1. Get rid of the union
2. Turn the 2 queries into derived tables
3. Select from them joining on entered_by.

Eg.

```
SELECT LineItems.ENTERED_BY, [NO OF LINE ITEMS], [NO OF INVOICES] 
FROM
(SELECT ENTERED_BY,COUNT(entered_by) 'NO OF LINE ITEMS' 
FROM im_invoice, im_invoice_line_item,im_invoice_inventory   
WHERE invoice_rid = invoice_fk  
AND invoice_inventory_rid = invoice_inv_fk
AND enter_date BETWEEN dateadd(mm, -3, getdate()) AND dateadd(mm,0,getdate())
GROUP BY entered_by) AS LineItems 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT entered_by, count(invoice_num) 'NO OF INVOICES' 
FROM im_invoice  
WHERE enter_date BETWEEN dateadd(mm, -3, getdate()) AND dateadd(mm,0,getdate())  
GROUP BY entered_by ) AS invoices 
ON invoices.entered_by = LineItems.ENTERED_BY
```